# Define the return type of a function depending on the real value of an argument

Tags: python, python-typing

I know that with `TypeVar` you can define the return type of a function
depending on the type of one its arguments. However, I want the type based on
the content of an argument.

For example, the function `open` returns different types depending on the
content of the `mode` argument:

```py
a = open("/etc/fstab", "r")
b = open("/etc/fstab", "rb")
```

In this case my `pyright` says that `a` is a `TextIOWrapper` and `b` is a
`BufferedReader`.

I also realized that my pyright infers the correct type with this code:

```py
mode = "rb"
a = open("/etc/fstab", mode)
```

but if I do:

```py
def funny(mode: str):
    a = open("/ect/fstab", mode)
```

then pyright infers `IO[Any]`. So clearly pyright take more than the literal
value of `mode` into consideration. So how is pyright inferring the type
correctly? Is this because the type hints of `open` or is it some kind of
"harcoding" of pyright for the function `open`?

Comment: I suspect there's  `@overload` for `open` somewhere that defines the return value for specific values of `mode`.

Comment: Note that in the first example, the type of `mode` is inferred as `Literal["rb"]`, not `str`.

Comment: @Barmar do you know where the typing hints for `open` is in the source code? I cannot find it.

Comment: It might not be in the python code, `pyright` may have its own set of type hints for all the built-ins.

Comment: Does that mean that build-ins do not have "official" type hints declarations in the source code?

Comment: The type hints for Python builtins can be found in TypeShed; `open` specifically is found [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1476). It uses `overload` in much the same way Barmar suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the `typing.overload` decorator and the `Literal` type.

```
type TextReadModes = Literal['r', 'r+']
type BinaryReadModes = Literal['rb', 'rb+']

@overload
def open(filename, mode: TextReadModes, ...) -> TextIOWrapper:
    ...

@overload
def open(filename, mode: BinaryReadModes, ...) -> BufferedReader:
    ...
```